# Getting ERROR: unrecognized configuration parameter "gp_strict_xml_parse" while restoring backup to 5.x Greenplum DB

Tags: linux, greenplum

I am currently using 4.3.0 GreenPlum version and now I want to move to 5.8.0 GreenPlum version which is the lastest one. Since, my old setup contains a lot of data, I want to backup and restore the data.

For backing up I ran the following command on my 4.3.0 Greenplum machine:

```
gp_dump --gp-d <Backup Location> <DB_Name>
```

This command executed successfully and I got the backup of the DB specified in the command.
Now, when I run the command, i.e.

```
gp_restore --gp-d <Backup Location> --gp-k <Timestmap Key generated while creating backup> -d <DB_Name>
```

to restore the backup on my 5.8.0 Greenplum, I get the following error:

```
20180607:10:28:12|gp_restore-[INFO]:-Analyzed command line options.
20180607:10:28:12|gp_restore-[INFO]:-Connecting to master segment on host localhost port 5432 database dadb.
20180607:10:28:12|gp_restore-[INFO]:-Reading Greenplum Database configuration info from master segment database.
20180607:10:28:12|gp_restore-[INFO]:-Preparing to restore the following segments:
20180607:10:28:12|gp_restore-[INFO]:-Segment 0 (dbid 2)
20180607:10:28:12|gp_restore-[INFO]:-Master (dbid 1)
20180607:10:28:12|gp_restore-[INFO]:-Starting to restore the master database.
20180607:10:28:12|gp_restore-[INFO]:-Creating thread to restore master database: host sjcinf6801vmw749 port 5432 database dadb
20180607:10:28:12|gp_restore-[INFO]:-Listening for messages from dbid 1 server (source) for dbid 1 restore
20180607:10:28:12|gp_restore-[INFO]:-Successfully launched Greenplum Database restore on dbid 1 to restore dbid 1
20180607:10:28:14|gp_restore-[INFO]:-restore started for source dbid 1, target dbid 1 on host sjcinf6801vmw749
20180607:10:28:14|gp_restore-[ERROR]:-restore failed for source dbid 1, target dbid 1 on host sjcinf6801vmw749
20180607:10:28:14|gp_restore-[ERROR]:-see error report for details
20180607:10:28:14|gp_restore-[INFO]:-Report results also written to ./gp_restore_20180607102011.rpt.

Greenplum Database Restore Report
Timestamp Key: 20180607102011
gp_restore Command Line: --gp-d /usr/ab/ --gp-k 20180607102011 -d dadb
Pass through Command Line Options: None
Compression Program: None

Individual Results
        Restore of database "dadb" on Master database: Failed with error:
{ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "gp_strict_xml_parse"
cat: write error: Broken pipe
20180607:10:28:14|gp_restore_agent-[ERROR]:-psql finished abnormally with return code 3.
20180607:10:28:14|gp_restore_agent-[ERROR]:-Finished with errors
}
```

After some digging I found out that "gp_strict_xml_parse" variable is no longer used in GreenPlum 5.x versions. Is there a way I can resolve this or any way to not include this variable while backing up the data?

Answer (score 0):

Greenplum version 5.x.x.x doesn't have gp_strict_xml_parse parameter.

In

While restore in 5.x and above(backup created from 4.3.x and above)
You can ignore this error/warnings while restoring. as these warning do not affect the restoration procedure.

(Note: I tried it , Same is mentioned in PIVOTAL'S document also)

Thanks
Gurupreet Singh

Answer (score 0):

adding to Gurupreet's reply above:

Details may be found in the release notes for each version of Greenplum 5.x

https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/500/relnotes/GPDB_500_README.html

[image: GPDB Release Notes]